# What is the problem with my Love2D Support extension for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, love2d

I am trying to run Lua directly from VS Code. I installed the Love2D Support extension for this. But the program does not run with Ctrl+L.
Here is where Love is installed on my computer:
[image]

These are my settings for the Love2D Support extension:
[image]

I don't understand why Love is not working from VS Code with Ctrl+L.

Comment: what do you mean with "does not run" and "is not working"  is nothing happening at all? are there error messages? did you change keybindings? ctrl + L selects the current line by default

Comment: @piglet Nothing happens at all. I didn't change keybindings. I press Ctrl+L and everything stays as it is

Comment: but according to the documentation Ctrl + L selects the current line.

Comment: @Piglet So how am I supposed to run the program from VS Code?

Comment: could use zerobrane, has pretty straight forward love2d set up

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening in VSCode, but you can drag the folder your main.lua file is in and drop it onto LÖVE2D to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The command to run Lua directly from VS Code using the LOVE2D extension is **alt + L** and
**Not ctrl + L** which selects the full line.

If the problem proceeds, make sure that LOVE is installed in **Program Files** because this is where the LOVE2D extension is going to look for LOVE by default.
Alternatively, you can specify LOVE's file path in the **LOVE2D extension's settings**.